# Oracle Distinct query - get yearly distinct values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table which has

- CustomerVisitID
- CustomerID
- Many other columns with values
- Year

I want to know no. of unique customers every year (with the other column values too)
I'm not doing a group by.

Querying something like

`select distinct(CustomerID) from CustomerVisits where year in (2016,2017,2018,2019)`

This doesn't query based on unique customers every year.

For Example, if customerID "5544" has come 4 times in 2016 and 3 times in 2018.
I want my query output to show 1 time in 2016 and 1 time in 2018.
My query shows a total of 1 time, which is not what i want.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use group by then

```
select year, count(distinct CustomerID) as CustomerID
from CustomerVisits 
where year in (2016,2017,2018,2019)
Group by CustomerID, year
```

As far as i understood your requirement, you can use two columns in distinct as follows:

```
select distinct year, CustomerID
    from CustomerVisits 
    where year in (2016,2017,2018,2019)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there an option to do it without the group by? I know group by works, but the example I shared is a very basic one and in my case, i'm actually joining some tables and have a larger dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep al columns you can use window functions

```
SELECT *
    , COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) OVER (PARTITION BY year) as customer_in_same_year 
FROM CustomerVisits 
WHERE year IN (2016,2017,2018,2019)
```

No group by used